# split up column value into empty column values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe `df`:

```
columnA columnB  columnC
A        A        10
A        B        NaN
A        C        20
B        A        30
B        C        NaN
A        D        NaN
D        C        15
```

How can I fill the `NaN`values in that case, that the next non `NaN´ value is diveded by the missing entries before and splitted (including the already filled row)? So in my case that the output is:

```
columnA columnB  columnC
A        A        10
A        B        10
A        C        10
B        A        30
B        C        5
A        D        5
D        C        5
```

Further explanation, in that case 20 was divided by 2 and leads to 10, and 15 was divided by 3 and leads to 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another *one-chained* variation using [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['columnC'] = (df['columnC'].fillna(0).groupby(df['columnC'].notna().cumsum()
                 .shift().fillna(0)).transform('mean'))
```

---

```
  columnA columnB  columnC
0       A       A     10.0
1       A       B     10.0
2       A       C     10.0
3       B       A     30.0
4       B       C      5.0
5       A       D      5.0
6       D       C      5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`groupby.transform('mean')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) on custom groups:

```
# group values with next non-NA
g = df.loc[::-1, 'columnC'].notna().cumsum()[::-1]

# compute the mean
df['columnC'] = df['columnC'].fillna(0).groupby(g).transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
  columnA columnB  columnC
0       A       A     10.0
1       A       B     10.0
2       A       C     10.0
3       B       A     30.0
4       B       C      5.0
5       A       D      5.0
6       D       C      5.0
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

Comment: @PV8 please provide a reproducible example. Which pandas version do you have? Can you try `g = df.loc[::-1, 'columnC'].notna().cumsum()[::-1]`?

Comment: @PV8 I'd appreciate feedback since the other answer just reused the same logic as mine with a different way to set up the grouper.

Comment: that one works above

Comment: @PV8 that's because you likely use an older pandas, in the latest versions you don't need to reindex the grouper it's realigned automatically.